# Passing parameters in Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am working with Sharepoint 2003. I want to pass data from one web part to other like select a drop down in one web part and the other gets updated. I am pretty new to SharePoint please suggest me any tutorials, links sample code to do that.

Thanks for help.

kind regards
vivek

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is specified by creating connectable web parts. See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx

Although it is for SharePoint 2010 and 2007, but concepts are same.

Comment: Well I am creating my web part in ASP.Net (Wrapping my user control inside the Web Part). any help on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Madhur's link is good although you'll have to make sure you don't try to use the Asp.Net WebPart infrastructure to create your WebPart.  That support was added in the 2007 cycle of the product.

You will want to extend Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart(office.12).aspx